# Unset array in multi dimensional array php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multi dimensional array and I try to add up the sum of audience if they have the same division_id but different post_page_id and return an array with total value of each division and unset the rest. I've tried double foreach but it did not work. Any help? Thanks

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [post_page_id] => 22130
            [audience] => 276
            [type] => facebook
            [division_id] => 1
            [tw_audience] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [post_page_id] => 22465
            [audience] => 6
            [type] => facebook
            [division_id] => 1
            [tw_audience] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [post_page_id] => 22189
            [audience] => 175
            [type] => twitter
            [division_id] => 2
            [tw_audience] => 
         )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [post_page_id] => 23044
            [audience] => 180
            [type] => facebook
            [division_id] => 2
            [tw_audience] => 
        )
)
```

So I want the output be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [post_page_id] => 22130, 22465
            [audience] => 282
            [type] => facebook
            [division_id] => 1
            [tw_audience] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [post_page_id] => 22189, 23044
            [audience] => 180
            [type] => twitter+facebook
            [division_id] => 2
            [tw_audience] => 175
         )

)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the result to look like, given the data here?

Comment: just edited, basically, I would like to merge arrays and sum up the audience and unset the one being merged. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associative arrays are your friend.

```
$result = array ();
foreach ($input as $inp)
{
    $idx = $inp ['division_id'];
    if  (isset ($result [$idx]))  //  New result, just copy it across
    {
        $result [$idx] = $inp;
        //  Since we are going to have multiple pages, turn the page_id into an array
        $result [$idx]['post_page_id'] = array ($inp ['post_page_id']);
    }
    else  //  Already exists - add the totals to the existing one
    {
        $result [$idx]['audience'] += $inp ['audience'];
        $result [$idx]['post_page_id'][] = $inp ['post_page_id'];
    }
}
//  Now, I assume you want to get rid of duplicates
foreach ($result as &$r)
{
    //  &$r means you are working with a pointer to the original, not a copy
    //  so changes are applied back to the original
    $r ['post_page_id'] = array_unique [$r ['post_page_id']];
    //  and if you really want the pages in comma-delimited format...
    $r ['post_page_id'] = implode (', ', $r ['post_page_id']);
}
```

You might want to do the same with sources as for post_page_id but implode them with '+'.

Comment: Snap! Though your fifth line should probably be `if (!isset...`.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is not to unset the elements of the current array, but rather write to a new one, merging to that as you go. Modifying an array's structure as you're iterating through it is usually a bad idea.

If you want to merge by `division_id`, you can write to the new array using that value as the array key. Then just check if it already exists - if it doesn't, copy the row in there, if it does, merge the values you want to merge.

Assuming your original array is in a variable called `$originalArray`:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($originalArray as $row) {
    $divID = $row['division_id'];
    // Check if this division_id has occurred before
    if (!isset($newArray[$divID])) {
        // Add in the first row if not
        $newArray[$divID] = $row;
    } else {
        // Otherwise, merge it into existing row

        // Merge audience
        $newArray[$divID]['audience'] += $row['audience'];

        // Merge post IDs
        $newArray[$divID]['post_page_id'] .= ', ' . $row['post_page_id'];

        // Merge type - need to account for duplicates
        $typeVals = explode('+', $newArray[$divID]['type']);
        if (!in_array($row['type'], $typeVals)) {
            $newArray[$divID]['type'] .= '+' . $row['type'];
        }
    }

}

// Overwrite original array, and use array_values() to reset keys if needed
$originalArray = array_values($newArray);
unset($newArray, $typeVals);
```

You may need to refine the merging methods depending on the exact data types, but you should get the idea.